# Linux/Debian History: what Debian version became able to download and install packages from the Internet (with apt commands)?

Tags: debian, apt, history

For my Linux culture: what was the first version of *Debian*
to become able to install packages from the Internet by the mean of the `apt` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, I think that would be [Debian 1.3](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/1997/msg00013.html), *before* apt was available (actually even earlier with Debian 1.1, as [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754934/70524) shows):

> With this release, it is very important to upgrade our "dpkg" package
> tool first, before you upgrade other packages in an older Debian
> system. [...]
>
> Once that has been done, you should be able to upgrade the entire
> system automatically using our "dselect" tool. If you are connected to
> the Internet you will not need to retrieve any other files manually,
> "dselect" will automatically retrieve and install the rest of Debian
> 1.3 for you.

So I'd say `dselect` was able to download and install packages from the internet.

Release notes of [Debian 2.0](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/1998/msg00015.html), the next release,  mention being able to download and install packages with apt:

> 2. apt-get
>    This is the command line part of Debian's future
>    package manager.  It knows how to order packages and will
>    download them from a local archive, http, and FTP sites.

The notes go on to mention the "Bo" version, that's Debian 1.3, so in Debian 1.3 we would have been able to use apt to download and install packages as well. (Though it was only included with 2.1, again as per [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754934/70524).)

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if I can Virtualbox/Vangrant a _Debian 2.0_ system, attempt an apt-get update/upgrade after that and if it will still find the repositories. I think they might be closed for a long time, now.

Comment: I see first `apt` only on [Potato = 2.2](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/DebianPotato)?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Debian has been able to download its components from the Internet since [Debian 1.1](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/1996/msg00021.html):

> The package tool can even automatically
> retrieve the programs you've requested via FTP.

The package tool here is `dselect`. It acquired this capability just after the beta release of 1.1; [the beta instructions](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/1996/msg00012.html) announce it as forthcoming:

> We have a tool that allows "dselect" to automaticaly retrieve packages
> via FTP, which makes the system much easier to install for net users.
> We'd like this to be part of the release, but it is currently a bit too
> buggy to be in the beta test. We'll try to get it in to beta status soon.

`apt` has been available in various guises since 1998, but the first Debian release to include it was [Debian 2.1 (Slink)](https://www.debian.org/releases/slink/i386/release-notes.en.txt), which included `apt` 0.1.8. The package [can still be found in the Slink repository](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/slink/main/upgrade-2.0-i386/).

Comment: Yes, I'm searching information with `apt`.

Comment: My question is "

_For my Linux culture: what was the first version of Debian
to become able to install packages from the Internet by the mean of the __apt__ commands?_" What is missing?

Comment: `dselect` also had the capability to download via http - i can't remember when that was added.  dselect had kind of a plugin-like model for working with different kinds of repos, there were methods for local filesystem, nfs, cdrom, floppy disks, ftp, http & https. maybe others too (it's been too long, can't remember the details). apt was added as a dselect method.  BTW, dselect still exists today (in its own package) and was first added to dpkg in Nov 1994 with version 0.93.13 (and was originally a perl script...as was dpkg until the C version of dpkg was released with 0.93.50 in May 1995).

Comment: there's lots of interesting historical details to be found in `/usr/share/doc/dpkg/changelog.gz`